# HTML & JS: How to subscribe to events from an embedded webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, web, embed, ipfs

I'm experimenting with building modular stand-alone (serverless) websites that can be hosted on [IPFS](https://ipfs.io/). One of the techniques I'm using to make the websites modular is by splitting single webpages across multiple HTML files and combining them by embedding them into each other,

for example:

Webpage files: Home.html, Sidebar.html

Code in Home.html:

```
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <!some code>
        <object id="Sidebar" data="Sidebar.html"></object>
        <!some more code>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Here is an image of what the website looks like. Note the scroll-bar that shows the the sidebar is embedded.
Website-with-Embedded-Sidebar :

[image]

I want to make that when elements of text in the sidebar (in the embedded Sidebar.html) are clicked, the JavaScript in the main page (Home.html) can react,

i.e. I want my JavaScript in Home.html to subscribe to events in the embedded Sidebar,html.

Any ideas on how best to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround solution that can in some cases be a suitable alternative is to call functions in the parent html file from the context of the embedded document. So instead of subscribing to click events in the embedded document from the parent document, I do it the other way round: handling the events in the embedded document and from there calling functions in the parent document.
Here is some working code:

Embedded HTML document (in a file called embedded_file.html):

```
<body>
  <div onclick="ClickHandler(this)">Test</div>
  <script>
    var ClickHandler = function(sender) {
      parent.OnEmbeddedDocClick(sender);
    };
  </script>
</body>
```

Main HTML page:

```
<body>
  <object data="./embedded_file.html"></object>
  <script>
    var OnEmbeddedDocClick = function(sender) {
      window.alert("Text in embedded file got clicked.");
    };
  </script>
</body>
```

Note that to test this, most browsers require these two files to be hosted on some form of web server instead of being stored on the local machine's filesystem, otherwise the browser's [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) blocks the embedded file from accessing the javascript in the parent html file.
Hosting the files on IPFS and testing it from there was enough to evade this issue.